# Cannot use mobile internet when in range of wifi

Tags: lumia, wifi, cellular-data, lumia-925

I have a problem with using mobile internet on my Nokia Lumia 925. When my wifi is on, everything works as it should. When I turn off wifi, my phone should switch to mobile internet (this is turned on). But this only happens when I'm **not** in the range of my wireless router.

So for example, I have a wifi connection, I turn it off and I take my phone for a walk in my garden. Then I only have mobile internet when I move outside the range of my wireless router.

Does anyone knows a solution for this annoying problem?

Edit:
I have sent the phone to nokia for revision and they say that the wifi chip was malfunctioning. After repair everything works great.

Comment: What happens if you move out of range and get mobile internet working, then move back in range?  Does it continue to work?

Comment: Have you checked your APN settings?

Comment: the problem which you have stated is not clear enough

Comment: Do you get the EDGE or 3G or whatever symbol near Network Indicator ?

Comment: This doesn't match my experience, with a Lumia 1020 running 8.1

Answer (score 1):

It is normal. You have to switch off mobile data if you want your WI-FI to auto-search in range connections. If you keep both active, then your phone will switch betwen them as long as one of them become unreachable :)

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The OP is asking about using **mobile data** while wifi is off (but a wifi router is in range), not the other way around. The symptoms described are most definitely *not* normal.

Comment: Then a Software update via Zune PC app might help

Comment: AFAIK the Zune software only works with WP7 devices, the Lumia 925 is WP8.

Comment: Whatever, He can always try to update...no metter what program his phone uses...